# Mass operator in lightcone quantization

Tags: string-theory, quantization

I am studying string theory following Tong's notes.

When deriving the mass operator in covariant quantization, we can do the following:
From the constraints $(\partial_+X)^2=(\partial_-X)^2=0$, we can get the Virasoro constraints, and in particular
$$L_0-a=0$$
Since 
$$L_0=\frac{1}{2}\alpha_0^2+ \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\alpha_{-m}\alpha_{m}$$
and $\alpha_0^\mu$ is proportional to $p^\mu$, we can get easily that
[image]

Now, in lightcone quantization, Tong used the constraints and 
[image]

to extract

[image]

and get

[image]

**Question:** Why can't we use the same procedure as in covariant quantization, which is more elegant? Are the Virasoro constraints not the same?

Comment: Light-cone & covariant quantization are in principle equivalent. What same procedure?

Comment: @Qmechanic Procedure: using that $L_0-a=0$ as described for the covariant quantization above. But if I do that I just get the mass operator for covariant quantization again, which is different from the one for lightcone quantization, apparently.

Comment: @Qmechanic I described two procedures, one for covariant quantization and one for lightcone quantization. My question is: why not use the first procedure in the second case?